# How to setup a heatmap, for temperature on Grafana

Tags: heatmap, iot, grafana, temperature

I'd like to be able to setup a heatmap on Grafana that will show me the temperatures recorded over say a week showing me what the frequency of temperature over 24 hours. So for example I've noticed that my temperature seems to peak around 7PM so I would want 7PM to show the average darkest red blob to show that that is generally the warmest hour then the boxes getting lighter and going down as it goes on and cools. I have 3 sensors logging in an influx database tagged by sensor location. I've absolutely no idea how'd I'd even start with something like this. I've tried setting up a heatmap (which sounds like the sort of thing I'd want). I've also found carpet plot mentioned but haven't tried it yet and am unsure if it would do what I want. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this and how I'd proceed?

Thank you for your time.